# How to swap trc20 to trx with Python in one wallet address?

Tags: swap, cryptocurrency, tron, trx, usd

I need to **swap**(change) part of my **trc20** asset to **trx** in my  **Tron** wallet. Consider i have some data like this:

```
public_key="AAA"
private_key="PPP"
trc20_address="TR7NHqjeKQxGTCi8q8ZY4pL8otSzgjLj6t"
current_trc20_amount=100 usdt
```

So for example swap 2 usdt to trx.
Is it possible? How?

> I need this because i want to make transaction automatically and
> programmatically. And for sending trc20 we need some trx as fee.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Tron API along with a library like `tronpy`.
https://tronpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
https://developers.tron.network/
hope these helpful.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34884311)